# Perform a google image search using image upload through Android code

Tags: android, google-image-search

I am making an Android app for which I need to fetch results by using Image Search of google using Image upload option. I have checked for Google Goggles Api, but I think it is not working currently. Also, I am unable to find suitable API which does Image Search via Image upload. There is Image search via Text.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Google Image Search API` is currently Deprecated. But, you could use Bing's instead. [Here](http://learn-it-stuff.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-bing-custom-search-inside-your.html) is an example of retrieving images using it with Java. It is a good start for your application.

**EDIT:**
If you want to search by images there is an alternative called [tineye](http://www.tineye.com). They have an API for that.

Comment: But does bing allows Image Search using an Image as input? I don't think so.

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry. I didn't notice that you wanted to do it by image. However, there are alternatives. Have you seen [tineye](http://www.tineye.com)? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah!! I looked at that. Do you know if it has a limited free edition of its API?

Comment: [Yes](http://tineye.com/faq#image_copyright). The free edition lets you do 50 searches per day, and up to 150 per week.